# Radiculus function

Tags: terminology

Bill Gosper is convinced that he's seen the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ referred to in the mathematical literature as the "radiculus function". Can anyone support this? A Google search was unavailing.

Comment: My poor Latin leads me to translate "radiculus" into English as "rootlet".

Comment: In fact, it seems there is no sign of a "radiculus function" in a standard Google research. I also tried MathSciNet, again with no results. Maybe you should ask B. Gosper some more details about the "mathematical literature" he is talking about.

Comment: I guess this is a mixup with [radical function](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/radical-expressions/the-graph-of-a-radical-function).